# Missing \endcsname inserted with beamer document

Tags: beamer

I have created a beamer presentation in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) but I don't know what my error means

```
>Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.99 \end{frame}
```

This is my tex

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title{Gettysburg Cemetery Dedication}
\author{Abraham Lincoln}
\institute{United States of America}
\date{19 Nov 1863}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage % beamer’s \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\begin{itemize}
\item Agenda
\item Review
\item Summary
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\tableofcontents

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Agenda}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Agenda}
\begin{itemize}
\item Met on battlefield (great)
\item Dedicate portion of field --- fitting!
\item Unfinished work (great tasks)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Not on Agenda!}
\begin{itemize}
\item Dedicate
\pause\item Consecrate
\pause\item Hallow (in narrow sense)
\pause\item Add or detract
\pause\item Note or remember what we say
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Review}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Key Objectives \& Success Factors}
\begin{itemize}
\item What makes nation unique:
\begin{itemize}
\item Conceived in Liberty
\item are equal
\end{itemize}

\begin{block}{Shared vision:}
\begin{itemize}
\item  New birth of freedom.
\item  Gov't of/for/by the people.
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Organizational Overview}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{gettysburg_graph}
\end{figure}
%\begin{equation}
%\lable{Four Score and Seven}
%-(4 * 20 + 7) = -87
%\end{equation}
\end{frame}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Summary}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Summary}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}
\begin{itemize}
\item New nation
\item Civil war
\item Dedicate field
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}
\begin{itemize}
\item Dedicated to unfinished work
\item New birth of freedom
\item Government not perish
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I believe that the width argument to `\begin{column}` is mandatory: so something like `\begin{column}{0.4\linewidth}` should be used.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  You've identified your problem clearly here, but your example is much too long; please look into how to create a minimal working example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), which will make it much easier for people to isolate your problem and help you solve it.  More often than not, it will help you solve it yourself, as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes in your code:

1. You have `\lable` instead of `\label` in an equation (it's commented out in your code but once you uncomment it you'll get an error).
2. The `column` environment requires a length specifying the width.

The corrected code (I marked the changes using `%HERE`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Organizational Overview}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
%\begin{equation}
%\label{Four Score and Seven}% HERE
%-(4 * 20 + 7) = -87
%\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\section{Summary}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Summary}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}% HERE
\begin{itemize}
\item New nation
\item Civil war
\item Dedicate field
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}% HERE
\begin{itemize}
\item Dedicated to unfinished work
\item New birth of freedom
\item Government not perish
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```